# I get the following Java error when I try to start Hive after installation

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am trying to install and run hive but I get the following error when I call `hive` from the command line:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hive/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Hive Session ID = f988816f-fcd8-4541-a1e7-3bc018c0214e
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
```

I have no knowledge of Java. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Have you installed Java and Hadoop before that?

Comment: You should downgrade your JDK to Java 8.

Comment: I have Java 8 and Java 11 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. so I downgrade the java version from 1.8 to 15 and work from me